# Why is my superuser failing to authenticate in psql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, psql, knex.js

I am attempting to run a test suite that includes knex and pg, but it fails with this error: 
`Knex:warning - Pool2 - Error: Pool was destroyed
Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user <username>
Unhandled rejection Error: Pool was destroyed`

My knexfile looks like this: (/knexfile.js)

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {

  testing: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'learnco_blog_test'
    },
    pool: {
      min:0,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'learnco_blog',
    },
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

};
```

I changed my pg_hba.conf file to "trust" all connections over IPV4 and IPV6, which I thought would resolve the issue, but it has persisted. Any ideas what else could be causing this? Could it be something in the knexfile? I am on psql 10.4, Ubuntu 16.04, knex 0.10.0, and pg 4.5.5. Thanks!

Also, if I run psql -h localhost -U  and put in my correct sudo password, I get an error saying password authentication failed for user .

Comment: I'm 100% sure this is a duplicate. Don't have time to find out to which one now though...

Comment: Also what is your postgres superusername? If its `postgres` and not your user that you are logged in you need to username too to be able to connect.